# Imprimir Datatable em uma DIV usando Bind ou Eval

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ado.net, datatable

É possível imprimir os dados de um `DataTable` (*codebehind*) em uma `div`?

Imprimir os dados do `datatable` no `Label`.

Como usar `bind` ou `eval`? Ou alguma outra forma?

Comment: Existe algo que te impeça de usar GridView ou Repeater ?

Answer (score 0):

O ideal é que você utilize um Gridview, Repeater ou um Listview (estes dois últimos parecem ser melhores para o que você quer, já que você pode montá-los dentro de um div como você quer). Este link explica como usar Repeater: http://www.macoratti.net/aspn_rep.htm

**Usando Repeater:**

Supondo que seu DataTable (dt) tenha as colunas id, nome, sexo, dtNascimento. Na sua página aspx ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<div>
   <asp:Repeater ID="rptMeuRepeater" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id")%><br />
         <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "nome")%><br />
         <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "sexo")%><br />
         <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "dtNascimento")%>
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

E para popular este repeater, faça no seu codebehind:

```
rptMeuRepeater.DataSource = dt;
rptMeuRepeater.DataBind();
```

**E fazendo como você pediu:**

Você pode sim percorrer as colunas de um DataTable e preencher seu label, dá mais trabalho; mas supondo que a Label que está na sua div tenha o id "lblTexto", seria mais ou menos assim (em c#):

```
Foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows){
  lblTexto.Text += r["id"] + "<br />";
  lblTexto.Text += r["nome"] + "<br />";
  lblTexto.Text += r["sexo"] + "<br />";
  lblTexto.Text += r["dtNascimento"] + "<br />";
}
```